# How Can I Have a Global Variable for React Itself in create-react-app (Or Otherwise Avoid Importing React Everywhere)?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

In older React applications I've worked on, which used Babel/Webpack directly, I was able to do:

```
import React from 'react';
global.React = React;
// rest of my imports
```

And therefore eliminate the need for every file in my codebase to have the same redundant and pointless import.

However, when I tried to do that same trick with a `create-react-app` app, it got mad at me trying to "import in the body", because of the imports that come after the `global.React = React` line.

So my question is, is it possible in `create-react-app` to somehow set React itself as a global variable, so that it *doesn't* have to be pointlessly/explicitly imported in every JSX using file?

Comment: Yes, place `global.React = React;` _after_ the rest of your imports. The error isn't complaining about the statement itself, it's complaining about the position of the statement. If you're using tsx, don't forget to add a definition file exposing the `React` namespace as an implicit global for your project.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @PatrickRoberts ... but it doesn't work. If I do that, I get `'React' is not defined                   no-undef` errors from the imports, because they're run before the global is set.

Comment: Then move the `import React from 'react'; global.React = React;` to the first file that imports React, since order of evaluation matters. If you just imported React in each file, as is the convention, you wouldn't need to worry about order of evaluation, but since you want to use implicit globals now you have to take that into account.

Comment: If I do that I get `'React' must be in scope when using JSX` from a sub-dependency of that file, down the chain a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NEWEST/EDITED ANSWER (as of December 2020)**

As of React 17 [the React import is no longer required for JSX](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html) (thanks for the comment kmui2!)

However, this does not mean you can just update React and stop using the `import`; you also have to switch your Babel transform (see: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9953)

**NEW/EDITED ANSWER (as of April 2020):**

Currently, the answer remains the same as the old one, below (ie. `create-react-app` can't support global `React`).  However, none other than Dan Abramov himself recently answered a [GitHub issue thread](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8643#issuecomment-613479847) with:

> There are planned changes to the JSX transform which will make it
> auto-import React. In that world, your global solution won't work, but
> it would solve the problem you're annoyed by.

So the good news is that the React team is planning to introduce a solution to the problem that will involve even *less* work than having to create a global variable!

**OLD ANSWER:**

The answer appears to be that `create-react-app` uses an ESLint rule: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/react-in-jsx-scope.md

As it says at the bottom of that rule:

> If you are setting React as a global variable you can disable this rule

... but for some reason the `create-react-app` people haven't chosen to account for that.

But I'd love to be wrong about this,and will happily remove this answer if anyone can provide a working one.

P.S. Interestingly enough in this thread https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4281 they actually provide a pattern for setting React globally, but when I follow their pattern (with a `'./globals'` import at the top) I still get the error ... again presumably because ESLint isn't aware of it.

P.P.S: I filed https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8643, in hopes that the `create-react` team will at least be willing to address why they used to allow this and don't anymore.  In a perfect world they'll provide a new way, but they might just say "don't use React globals".  Either way, I'll add a "P.P.P.S" when they respond.

Comment: Just an update: React 17 and some older specified major versions now include the new JSX transform that does not require this explicit React import. See https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html